# How do I find keywords in a character vector?

Tags: r, search, vector, keyword

I am a newcomer to r and I am trying to find a way to perform a keyword search against a character vector.

I have tried to set up a loop to compare the keywords against the vector. When I run the loop, all I get is a repeat of the code.

```
for(i in length(keywords)){
result = grep((keywords[i]), colours, value = TRUE)
}
```

If I run grep outside of the loop and substitute i with say 2 I get

[1] "green white red" "grey white blue"

which is the output I am looking for.

```
colours = c("blue yellow green",
           "orange brown black",
           "green white red",
           "turquoise brown crimson",
           "maroon purple navy",
           "grey white blue",
           "aquamarine seagreen olive",
           "khaki lemon sienna")

keywords = c("lemon",
             "white",
             "khaki",
             "blue",
             "pink")

for(i in length(keywords)){
result = grep((keywords[i]), colours, value = TRUE)
}
```

After the code has run, I would like to create a new vector called result which in this example contains the following elements:

```
"khaki lemon sienna"
"green white red" 
"grey white blue"
"khaki lemon sienna"
"blue yellow green" 
"grey white blue"
```

I would be very grateful for advice on how to do this properly

Answer (score 0):

If we are using a `for` loop, make sure the 'result' is not replaced in each iteration.   Also, `length` returns a single value, so looping through it is just the last value `keywords[length(keywords)]`, instead it can be `seq_along` (or `1:length(keywords)` - prefer to have `seq_along`)

```
result <- c()
for(i in seq_along(keywords)){
 result <- c(result, grep((keywords[i]), colours, value = TRUE))
 }

result
#[1] "khaki lemon sienna" "green white red"    "grey white blue"  
#[4]  "khaki lemon sienna" "blue yellow green"  "grey white blue"
```

Here, we update the 'result' by concatenating on each iteration and updating the 'result' vector

---

It can also be done without a loop if we create the 'keywords' as a `paste`d single string separated by `|` (OR - to match any of the keywords strings in the 'colours' vector)

Answer (score 0):

```
unlist(lapply(keywords, function(k) colours[grepl(k, colours)]))
#OR
colours[unlist(lapply(keywords, grep, colours))]
#[1] "khaki lemon sienna" "green white red"    "grey white blue"    "khaki lemon sienna"
#[5] "blue yellow green"  "grey white blue"
```